# How to record a visitors IP into a text file or into PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I would like to be able to record user's IP address into a text file or even into a DB when these users visit a specific page I setup. But I'm not even sure where to start. Can anyone give me some pointers on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the php manual http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php. You probably want $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to display your ip address.

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo "IP address= $ip";
```

The above code will display this IP address= 122.166.115.75

`$_SERVER` is an array and it contains lot of information as supplied by server and one of the element is '`REMOTE_ADDR`' which gives us the IP address. Here is another example of getting the server name using `$_SERVER`

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = www.plus2net.com
```

You can display all other elements of Array by using display **elements of array**. Here is a sample code.

```
while (list ($key, $val) = each ($_SERVER)) { 
$key -> $val 
}
```

After collecting the IP address we can store in mysql table. Along with IP address we can store referrer , browser details etc.

When visitors come to our website we can collect visitors IP address, referrer, browser details and others details and store them in a MySQL table.

Here is the dump of the table track

```
CREATE TABLE `track` (
`id` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`tm` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
`ref` varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',
`agent` varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',
`ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
`ip_value` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
`domain` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
`tracking_page_name` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

Note that the script already have mysql connection and here is the code to be used for logging visitor details to mysql table. We have used one sql insert query to add record to the table on each opening of the page.

```
$tm=time();
$ref=@$HTTP_REFERER;
$agent=@$HTTP_USER_AGENT;
$ip=@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO track(tm, ref, agent, ip, tracking_page_name) VALUES ('$tm','$ref','$agent','$ip','$tracking_page_name')";
$test=mysql_query($strSQL);
```

The above code will insert the visitor details to the table name **track** in mysql database.